# Tikz-Feynman: Alignment of multiple diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I am trying to recreate these two diagrams and align them nicely.

[image]

I was able to roughly recreate the two diagrams individually using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\diagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a [particle=\(h_0\)] -- [scalar] b --
  b -- [scalar] c [particle=\(h_0\)]
};
\path (b)--++(90:0.5) coordinate (A);
\draw [dashed] (A) circle(0.5) node[left] at (1.0,0.5) {$\tilde{f}$};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and

```
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a [particle=\(h_0\)]-- [scalar] b
-- [scalar, half left, edge label=\(\tilde{f}\)] c
-- [scalar, half left, edge label=\(\tilde{f}\)] b,
c -- [scalar] d [particle=\(h_0\)],
};
```

but I do not understand how I can get the scalar lines to line up by putting them in one diagram. If I put these pieces together I end up with a document with two pages, one diagram on each page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are these diagrams in an equation or a figure?

Comment: they will be in a figure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you are looking for the baseline key. However, I should say that I had some difficulties in *precisely* aligning them when keeping your original syntax, which is why now the second diagram is also of the form `\begin{feynman}...\end{feynman}`. Not sure what the problem was, but this seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base)]
\begin{feynman}
\diagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a [particle=\(h_0\)] -- [scalar] b -- [scalar] c [particle={\(h_0\)}]
};
\path (b)--++(90:0.5) coordinate (A);
\draw [dashed] (A) circle(0.5) node[left] at (1.0,0.5) {$\tilde{f}$};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base)]
\begin{feynman}
\diagram[layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a [particle=\(h_0\)]-- [scalar] b
-- [scalar, half left, edge label=\(\tilde{f}\)] c
-- [scalar, half left, edge label=\(\tilde{f}\)] b,
c -- [scalar] d [particle=\(h_0\)],
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Putting the two in one tikzpicture does the trick

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\diagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a [nudge=(180:5mm),particle=\(h_0\)] -- [scalar] b --
  b -- [scalar] c [nudge=(0:5mm),particle=\(h_0\)]
};
\path (b)--++(90:0.7) coordinate (A);
\draw [dashed] (A) circle(0.7) node[left] at (1.25,0.7) {$\tilde{f}$};
\diagram [xshift=5cm,layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a [particle=\(h_0\)]-- [scalar] b
-- [scalar, half left, edge label=\(\tilde{f}\)] c
-- [scalar, half left, edge label=\(\tilde{f}\)] b,
c -- [scalar] d [particle=\(h_0\)],
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```